# Numpy DeprecationWarning on boolean indexing

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, deprecation-warning

This code

```
import numpy as np

def some_method(y, threshold):
    print type(y), y.shape, y.dtype 
    c = np.zeros(y.shape)
    c[y > threshold] = 1
```

Results in

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (484L,) [('target', '<f8')]
DeprecationWarning: using a boolean instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  c[y > threshold] = 1
```

I can't find anything on this in Google nor in the numpy release notes. I'm assuming this is about indexing by booleans? I don't understand how this could possibly result in an error in the future, how can I fix this?

Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Numpy version: 1.8.0

EDIT: Added the print statement to the code to show the array is an ndarray

EDIT2: From the comments it became clear that this happens because `y` is a struct array and the correct way to do the check is `y['target'] > threshold`. However, `y` could have multiple columns, or even different column names, is there a way to do this flexibly with structured arrays?

Comment: `y` is not a numpy array, so `y > threshold` is not returning an array of bools, but a single `True` or `False`. When using a single boolean value to index an array, it is converted to `0` or `1`. It is this behavior that will change in the future: a single boolean, or a single float, will raise an error, they will not be converted to ints.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify, `y` is in fact a numpy array, see the edit.

Comment: Ok got it, I need to specify the column name. But `y` can have multiple columns, is there a way to flexibly do this?

Comment: A workaround for scalar indexing corner cases, until they can finally be truly fixed, is to call `np.asarray` on them. Actually in 1.9. this should already work, because it was an error anyway (since c is 0-d too)

Comment: ah, pff, nvm. you got a structured type, so the comparison doesn't work at all. In 1.9. you should get a warning that it will be an error in the future. use `y['target'] > threshold`

Comment: Thanks @seberg, I indeed figured out I should the column name, i.e. y['target'], see my earlier comment. But y could have multiple columns, or even different column names, is there no way to do this flexibly with structured arrays?