# Python 3.7 boolean indexing *warning* using 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, boolean

- Take a very large list such that for any number of reasons it and all the rest to come does not fit in available memory, here: `A = [ 2, -3, 10, 0.2]`
- Map the sign of its components: sign_A = `list(map(lambda u: (abs(u)==u), A))`
  You get `[True, False, True, True]`
- Do some logic where you need to operate on `abs_A = [abs(e) for e in A]`. So you flush `A` and you keep working with `sign_A` and `abs_A`. The logic yields components' indices of interest, say `i`, `k`, ... for the list `abs_A`.

The problem I have is when using the ternary operator `(falsevalue, truevalue)[condition]` to do some algebra on the ***signed*** components of **`A`**, e.g.:

```
abs_A[i]*(-1, 1)[sign_A[i]] + abs_A[k]**(-1, 1)[sign_A[k]]
# equivalently, can use:
# abs_A[i]*(-1, 1)[np.bool(sign_A[i])] + abs_A[k]**(-1, 1)[np.bool(sign_A[k])]
```

I get this warning:

> DeprecationWarning: In future, it will be an error for 'np.bool_'
>   scalars to be interpreted as an index.

The warning indirectly tells me that there is probably a better, more "pythonesque" way than my snippet to do this. I found relevant posts (e.g. [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7913) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282266/numpy-deprecationwarning-on-boolean-indexing)) but no suggestion as to how I should deal with it. Pointers anyone ?

Comment: Just replace `np.bool()` with `int()`: `abs_A[i]*(-1, 1)[int(sign_A[i])]+...`

Comment: `A` looks like a list, not an array.

Comment: @DYZ: I was just reading a comment by Jaime on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282266/numpy-deprecationwarning-on-boolean-indexing, suggesting the same. Tx.

Comment: The elements of `sign_A` are already booleans; and they work when indexing a tuple like (-1,1).

Comment: @hpaulj: Indeed they are and they do. But when using them as shown in black (in the snippet) I get the same error as when I use them with either the builtin `bool`or with `np_bool`.  I'm a newby in Python and that threw me off.

Comment: If `sign_A` is a list, as your code demonstrates, then the boolean indexing works.  It's when `sign_A` is made into an array that we get the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the warning, replace `np.bool()` with `int()`:

```
abs_A[i]*(-1, 1)[int(sign_A[i])] + ...
```

Answer (score 2):

With lists, the boolean indexing works fine:

```
In [21]: A = [ 2, -3, 10, 0.2]                                                  
In [22]: sign_A = list(map(lambda u: (abs(u)==u), A))                           
In [23]: abs_A = [abs(e) for e in A]                                            
In [24]: i=0; k=1                                                               
In [25]: abs_A[i]*(-1, 1)[sign_A[i]] + abs_A[k]**(-1, 1)[sign_A[k]]             
Out[25]: 2.3333333333333335
```

We do get the warning if we try to index with a numpy boolean:

```
In [26]: abs_A[i]*(-1, 1)[np.array(sign_A)[i]]                                  
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: In future, it will be an error for 'np.bool_' scalars to be interpreted as an index
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[26]: 2
```

We can get around that by making the `sign_A` array integer right from the start:

```
In [27]: abs_A[i]*(-1, 1)[np.array(sign_A,dtype=int)[i]]                        
Out[27]: 2
```

If we start with an array:

```
In [28]: B = np.array(A)
```

the sign array - using `where` to map directly onto (-1,1) space

```
In [30]: sign_B = np.where(B>=0,1,-1)                                           
In [31]: sign_B                                                                 
Out[31]: array([ 1, -1,  1,  1])
```

the abs array:

```
In [32]: abs_B = np.abs(B)
```

the recreated array:

```
In [33]: abs_B*sign_B                                                           
Out[33]: array([ 2. , -3. , 10. ,  0.2])
```

Comment: +1: @hpaulj: For me Boolean indexing throws the indicated warning (per my OP and your Output[26]).  I see from your very didactic answer (thanks a lot for it) that you use a Jupyter notebook.   Could a different linter explain the odd difference in behavior ?  I am on `vim` and use either `pylint`, `flake8` and/or `bandit`, on different aspects of the syntax (I did not just pile up 3 linters)...

Comment: My warning is from `numpy`, not a lint. 1.16.1

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution here is to use the syntax `truevalue if condition else falsevalue` in place of  `(falsevalue, truevalue)[condition]`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by DYZ from Mar 15 '19:

In this case remapping the sign function from boolean to integer led to the use of np.bool triggering

> DeprecationWarning: In future, it will be an error for 'np.bool_'
> scalars to be interpreted as an index.

Using `int()` instead resolved the issue.

A wrapper approach is less readable but would have also worked: `int(np.bool(sign_A[i]))`

In the more general case of numpy bitwise logical operators the same warning is triggered by e.g., by using an inequality check as an index:

```
result = X[np.less_equal(a, b)]
```

`X` could hold items of a type other than integer.

A suitable solution if X contained `float` items is:

```
result = float(X[np.less_equal(a, b)])
```

Alternatively,

```
result = X[np.less_equal(a, b)] 
return = float(result)
```

can be used with a function definition.

The latter `return` form is the way I resolved a Warning triggered today within a function definition. I was guided by DYZ's answer.